# Why does a signed shift right bring in 1s instead of just holding a 1 in the most significant spot?

Tags: java

...and bring in 0s.

For example:

```
1111 0110 >> 2
```

gives

```
11 1111 01
```

according to some notes.

Why are 1s brought in?  Why not just hold the left most bit at 1 and bring 0s in?

Isn't shifting to the right sort of like dividing by 2? If so shouldn't 0s be brought in?

Comment: Look up Two's Complement.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: Because a signed shift right is equivalent to dividing by 2.  Work it out.

Comment: Because that would make it an unsigned shift right, not a signed shift right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a right shift to be the same as dividing by 2. Assuming that’s a signed 8-bit quantity, this is `-128`:

```
1000 0000
```

This is `-64`:

```
1100 0000
```

So this is a counterexample to your suggestion.

Comment: basically when the MSB changes to a 1 this also changes the meaning of the other bits as now you add them to -128.  So in this example `-128 + 64 = -64`.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "sign extension" and it's there exactly in order to have the effect of dividing by two. If the leftmost bit became 0, the sign of the originally negative number would change into positive. If only the leftmost bit was kept one, and further bits changed to zero, the result would have nothing to do with division by two.

If you want zeros to be prepended on the left, there is a special operator for that: `>>>`.

NB Java has only one *unsigned* integer quantity, and it is `char`. On this data type, `>>` works by prepending zeros on the left.

Comment: Yes, I see now. It's all about understanding two's complement.